# Why can't I accept calls on my Droid X?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, motorola-droid-x

I recently [updated my Droid X](http://support.verizonwireless.com/pdf/system_update/droid_x.pdf) to version `4.5.621.MB810.Verizon.en.US`. I can't accept incoming calls though. The screen that allows you to either accept or decline a call doesn't appear anymore.

The top notification bar also disappeared around this time if that has anything to do with the problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that restarting it helped. Now the top, notification bar and the dialer appear. I think it may have something to do with the Messages app. As I unassociated my email account before restarting the phone.